# Compare one row to all other rows

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R

```
  ID     bay    row    tier
  1       1      2      80
  2       3      2      80
  3       2      5      06
  4       4      5      06
  5       23     6      82
  6       25     6      82
  7       24     6      82
  8       4      12     08
```

What I want to find is `row` and `tier` values are equal and at the same time `bay` should be an `odd` number and bay difference between two same `row and tier` entries should be `2`.

E.g

```
 ID     bay    row    tier
 1       1      2      80
 2       3      2      80
```

above two rows qualifies my condition `row and tier` are same with `bay` as odd number and difference between `two bay` numebers is `2` and I need to generate a flag which will get generated for both rows, lets say `1,2,3` which uniquely identifies the pairs

My desired dataframe would be

```
 ID     bay    row    tier   flag
 1       1      2      80     1
 2       3      2      80     1
 3       2      5      06     NA
 4       4      5      06     NA
 5       23     6      82     2
 6       25     6      82     2
 7       24     6      82     NA
 8       4      12     08     NA
```

How can I do it in r?

Comment: how do want to handle cases like 3 consecutive rows in a group satisfying the conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the subset as follows,

```
ind <- duplicated(df[c('row', 'tier')]) & df$bay%%2 == 1|
       duplicated(df[c('row', 'tier')], fromLast = TRUE) & df$bay%%2 == 1
df1 <- df[ind,]
df1 <- df1[!!with(df1, ave(bay, new, FUN = function(i) c(TRUE, diff(i) == 2))),]
df1
```

Which gives

> ```
>   ID bay row tier
> 1  1   1   2   80
> 2  2   3   2   80
> 5  5  23   6   82
> 6  6  25   6   82
> ```

To get the flag,

```
df$flag <- cumsum(c(1, diff(which(ind)) != 1))[match(df$ID, df1$ID)]
df
```

Which gives,

> ```
> ID bay row tier flag
> 1  1   1   2   80    1
> 2  2   3   2   80    1
> 3  3   2   5    6   NA
> 4  4   4   5    6   NA
> 5  5  23   6   82    2
> 6  6  25   6   82    2
> 7  7  24   6   82   NA
> 8  8   4  12    8   NA
> ```

Comment: @Aramis7d mind deleting your comment? That issue is fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

using `tidyverse`, you can try something like this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(row,tier) %>%
  mutate(flg = if_else(bay %%2 >0, 1, 0)) %>%
  filter(flg == 1) %>%
  mutate(df2 = lead(bay,1) - bay) %>%
  filter(df2 == 2) %>%
  select(-df2) %>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate(flg = 1:n()) %>%
  right_join(df) %>%
  mutate(flg = coalesce(flg,lag(flg,1)))
```

which gives:

```
     ID   bay   row  tier   flg
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     2    80     1
2     2     3     2    80     1
3     3     2     5     6    NA
4     4     4     5     6    NA
5     5    23     6    82     2
6     6    25     6    82     2
7     7    24     6    82    NA
8     8     4    12     8    NA
```

Comment: Upvote for seemingly being the only one to have thoroughly read the question instead of just trying to replicate the expected output (like me).

Comment: To be honest, this is why I love the `%>%` operator.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df1)[, .I[all(bay%%2 == 1) & diff(bay)==2], .(grp = rleid(bay%%2),row, tier)]$V1
df1[i1, flag := 1
  ][!is.na(flag), flag := as.numeric(.GRP), .(row, tier)]
df1
#    ID bay row tier flag
#1:  1   1   2   80    1
#2:  2   3   2   80    1
#3:  3   2   5    6   NA
#4:  4   4   5    6   NA
#5:  5  23   6   82    2
#6:  6  25   6   82    2
#7:  7  24   6   82   NA
#8:  8   4  12    8   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach. You mention you just need a unique identifier. If the numbers don't have to be sequential, it can be achieved like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df$flag=NA
group = df %>% group_indices(row,tier)
idx = which(df$bay %% 2==1 & (df$bay - lag(df$bay,default=-1)==2 | group != lag(group,default=-1)))
df$flag[idx]=group[idx]
```

Output:

```
  ID bay row tier flag
1  1   1   2   80    1
2  2   3   2   80    1
3  3   2   5    6   NA
4  4   4   5    6   NA
5  5  23   6   82    3
6  6  25   6   82    3
7  7  24   6   82   NA
8  8   4  12    8   NA
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: your second approach fails if you change `bay` to 27 for `ID` number 7. you're not checking for the `difference of 2` condition.

Comment: Actually, both your approaches fail for that condition.

Comment: @Florian How can we add `difference of 2` condition in your dplyr approach?

Comment: Sorry Neil, Aramis, I actually missed that condition. Maybe you can unaccept the answer Neil?

Comment: @Florian `dplyr` approach is simple. if we can add `difference of 2` condition in that

Comment: Agreed, should be easily possible with checking the difference with lag() for example. I'll see if I can make that work.

Comment: @Neil you can refer to my answer for using `lead()` to get the difference between consecutive rows. Also, `dplyr` is a subset of `tidyverse`.

Comment: @Florian sorry, but it also fails on the `uniquely identify each pair` part, since if you have multiple pairs within a group, they get the same id.  please don't hate me :P

Comment: No problem at all haha, question is indeed a bit vague about that. Neil, I suggest just accepting Aramis answer if you want numbering pair-wise ;)

Comment: A fun question nonetheless. :) Thanks to @Neil

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this crappy for loop,but it works

```
df$flag = NA

for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for(j in 2:nrow(df)) {
    if(df$row[i] == df$row[j]){
      if(df$tier[i] == df$tier[j]){
        if(df$bay[i] %% 2 != 0){
          if(df$bay[j] %% 2 != 0){
            if(abs(df$bay[i] - df$bay[j]) == 2){
              df$flag[i] = i
              df$flag[j] = i
         }
       }

      }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```